# How can i tell if my Julia session is still somewhere in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, save, command-history

I was working in Julia on VS Code and trying to save the command history.
ChatGPT told me to get an extension for it, so I went to extensions.
VS Code told me I should reload existing extensions, so I did.
Then it opened a new terminal and I can't find anything I was working on before.

Is the old session still active somewhere? I can't find any buttons or menu items for that, but
I seem to have trouble finding things in VS Code generally.
Otherwise, it is likely that my command history is saved somewhere?

Comment: Old session is gone but Julia likely still has your command history if you press up arrow in the REPL

Comment: It does! Now how do I save the command history?
And what probably happened, anyway? What was I supposed to do?
Should I really be using a different IDE? What's good with Julia?

Answer (score 1):

Julia command history is saved in Julia's logs directory

```
C:\Users\XXX.XXXX\\.julia\logs
```

(In my case using VS Code and Windows 10) as answered in this thread by [Stefan Karpinski] [1](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-can-i-view-the-whole-command-history/17987/3?u=cesquerre)